# Переход по ссылкам на PHP.

Tags: php, ссылки

Доброго времени суток.
Подскажите как сделать переход по ссылкам.
Надо сделать парсер, и переходить по всем ссылкам на спарсенной странице.

Comment: лично я не понял что требуется.

Comment: Уточните, вам надо загрузить в PHP скрипт все страницы по ссылкам, или показать пользователю в браузере все страницы одна за одной?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
//загружаем первую страницу
$page = file_get_contents('http://ваша.страница.ру/страница1.php?blabla=суть.думаю.ясна');
if( preg_match('~<a.*?href=(['"]*)(.*?)\\1~is', $page, $m ) ){
   foreach( $m[1] as $k=> $url ){
     // $url = это мы распарсили ссылку. Но нужно еще учесть что ссылки могут быть относительными
      file_get_contents( $url ); // перещли по распарсенной url

   }
}
```